# github contributions for branch different than master

Tags: git, github

Why, if I make a commit in, let's say, `develop` branch, doesn't this appear in my contribution?

I expected that if I merge that branch into `master` then all the commits made into `develop`  or other branches would be visible. But that doesn't seem to be the case.

Is there anyway to do so? or the commit has to be made directly into `master` ?

Comment: When you merge to master all of your commits should be seen in your contribution. If this isn't the case something went wrong and you should contact support

Comment: Did you squash the merge, or rebase? If the former, all of the previous work becomes a single commit on master. Is this a public repo you could give a link to?

Comment: Make sure you have added and commited all files you want to push? Use `git status` to see what is not added and then `git add <files>` follwed by `git commit`

Comment: RTFM: https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/

Answer (score 5):

Github only counts contributions made to the default branch(which is usually master) but not those to any other branch. You can change your default branch from master to develop(from setting of that repository), if you work on it more often and wish to see contribution made to develop to appear as contributions. More information on github help page.

Comment: The OP specifically points out that he expects commits to other branches to be counted ***once sucn a branch is merged into master***. Your answer does not say anything specific about this situation, while comments below the OP do - Care to elaborate on this situation?